# Need help understanding file uploads in Python Flask, w/ and w/o Javascript + Ajax

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, file-upload, flask

I am writing a webapp that lets the user upload photos, and then returns data about those photos to the front end to trigger some activity.

I started this off using a tutorial/guide I found online, [here](http://code.runnable.com/UiPcaBXaxGNYAAAL/how-to-upload-a-file-to-the-server-in-flask-for-python)

I was however very surprised to find that this worked without javascript. I do not understand how pressing the button sends a request for there to be a pop-up window asking to select a file. How does it know that the button is for file uploading? No where in the HTML do I give it an obvious attribute that tells it to upload a file, and nowhere in python/Flask do I select the button used for uploading.

I also noticed, to my surprise, that in the example given, the route MUST be called "/upload" to work. Again, I can not see where any of this is defined or where I could change it. The only files used for the demo on that link (which is the basis of my webapp) are app.py and index.html (the setup.py file does not seem to be needed to run the webserver)

As my webapp has progressed, I tried to add a javascript file that would take a response from the /uploads route and display it on the front end, but soon ran into trouble. It seems I can only run /uploads from whatever mysterious force is currently running it. My javascript can't access it, and so I have no way of getting the response into JS so that I can display it on the front end in the way I want.

**Can someone help me understand how the file upload server in the link works, so that I can modify it to work with my JavaScript?**

Please note that my webapp is basically just the program in that link with a bunch of analysis done on the files that are uploaded. The only change I made in terms of how the webapp works is that instead of redirecting you to the uploaded file, it should return a string with information on that file.

I don't feel it is worth posting too much of my python and HTML code, since all the important stuff is in that link, but the javascript file is below.

```
    "use strict";

var main = function() {
    console.log("i am functioning!")

    var show_similar_img = function(){
        //Read megastatus
        $.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                url: "/upload",
                // contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: "string"
        })
        .done(function(media_info){
            console.log(media_info)
        });
    }

    $("#upload-btn").on("click",function(){
        console.log("button pressed!")
        show_similar_img()
    })
}

console.log("i am being run!")
$(document).ready(main);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<input>` element's `type` attribute is `file`, which is how the browser knows how to handle it in the particular way that it does--as you noticed, by opening a pop-up modal window which prompts the user to select a file.

The route has to be called *upload* because the `<form>` element's `action` attribute value is also called *upload*. You could change the name of the route if you also changed the action of the form.

You can in fact access file information (for a file associated with the input element) using JavaScript thanks to the File API. Mozilla Developer Network has an excellent guide for it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

With regards to your actual implementation: first, you'll also want to prevent your form submission from being handled in the 'regular' (synchronous) way, so you'll need to call `preventDefault` on the event:

```
$("#upload-btn").on("click",function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("button pressed!")
    show_similar_img()
 })
```

Second, I am assuming that you want to actually send the file to the server (run on Python/Flask), so you want your AJAX request to be a POST rather than a GET. Therefore you'll need to modify your `show_similar_img`, to send the request as a POST and also to include the file in the data of the request, using the aforementioned File API. Something like this:

```
var show_similar_img = function(){
    var formData = new FormData();
    var file = $("input[type='file']")[0].files[0];
    formData.append("file", file);

    $.ajax({
        url : "/upload",
        type : "POST",
        data : formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    })
    .done(function(media_info){
        console.log(media_info)
    });

}
```

Edit--I should add that I'm not really familiar with Flask or the intricacies of its `request` object. I assume that regardless of whether the file is uploaded as part of a form submission or asynchronous request that it would still be accessible at `request.files['file']`, but it is possible that Flask doesn't make asynchronously uploaded files available in the `request.files` dictionary. I am very sure, though, that the file would be accessible *somewhere* on the `request` object, so you may need to refer to the Flask documentation. You could also use `pdb` to add a breakpoint in your server-side code and inspect the `request` object to see what it holds (and where it holds it).